# Load different JS file for mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript

So I have two different JS files to load: one for desktop and a different one for mobile. And I have used this code:

```
<script>
if ( $(window).width() < 739) {      
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/js-file-for-mobile.js"></script>  
} 
else {
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/js-file-for-desktop.js"></script>  
}
</script>
```

But the only script that loads is the desktop one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the answer:

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 900) {
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/desktop.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>

<script>
if (screen && screen.width < 900) {
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/mobile.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Verified and working!

Comment: Why backslash in closing script tag?

Comment: @KillerDeath Because otherwise it would be a syntax error, since the browser's engine would interpret the first "</script>" occurrence as the closing tag of the outer <script>.

Answer (score 3):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";

if (screen.width() < 739) 
{
    js.src = "js/mobile.js";
}
else
{
    js.src = "js/desktop.js";
}

head.appendChild(js);
```

Comment: Thank you, but now even the desktop file isn't loading :(

Comment: You are using jquery, did you include it?

Answer (score 0):

I think checking screen size to decide if its mobile or desktop browser is a little risky as it may confuse sometime with iPad or small screen desktop.

So, We can navigator to check if its mobile or desktop and den our job accordingly.

```
//returns true if user is using one of the following mobile browsers
var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)
```

your e.g:

```
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)) {      
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/js-file-for-mobile.js"></script>  
} 
else {
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://example.com/js-file-for-desktop.js"></script>  
}
</script>
```